# Prove the following problem is NL-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, space-complexity

Suppose
$$A = \left\{\langle G, d, s, t\rangle \;\Bigg|\;
\begin{array}{l}
  \text{\(G\) undirected}, \\
  \text{\(s\) and \(t\) are nodes in \(G\)}, \\
  \text{there is a path of length \(d\) from \(s\) to \(t\) and no path of shorter length}
\end{array}\right\}$$
I can easily see that this language is in NL, but I am having trouble proving that this is NL-complete.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly length $d$? Or is $\geq d$ okay?

Comment: it has to be exactly d. in other words, the shortest path from s to t has length d.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G'$ be the graph with self-loops added to every vertex. Take $n$ copies $G'_1,G'_2,\ldots,G'_n$ (without the edges) and connect $x \in G'_i$ to $y \in G'_{i+1}$ if $(x,y) \in G'$. The shortest path between $s \in G'_1$ and $t \in G'_n$, if any exists, is now of length exactly $n-1$.

Comment: If I'm interpreting correctly, you can get rid of the self loops and explicitly say something like "connect $x\in G_{i}$ to $y \in G_{i+1}$ if $(x,y)\in E(G)$ or $x=y$ (in $G$)", then we still have a simple graph.

Comment: Right, this is the same thing.