$L\in \text{DSPACE}(\log^2 (n))$
We consider a representation of directed graphs that assumes layers in the graph. That is, we denote by $G = \{V_1, V_2, . . . , V_k; E\}$ the graph whose vertex set is $V =\cup_{i=1}^kV_i$ and $E$ may only contain edges $(u, u')$ such that
$u \in V_i$ and $u' \in V_{i+1}$ (i.e., from a layer $V_i$ to the consecutive layer $V_{i+1}$) for $1 \leq i < k$. Other edges are not allowed (this should not be verified when $G$ is given as input).
Define:
$$L= \{\langle G = {V_1, V_2, \cdots, V_k; E}, s, t\rangle: s \in V_1, t \in V_k \text{ and there is an even number of paths from s to t }\}$$
I want to Prove that $L\in \text{DSPACE}(\log^2(n))$ using the Savitch theorem. My question is how do I start to prove this applying the Savitch theorem?

see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7115/prove-the-following-problem-is-nl-complete

@ReinerCzerwinski I don't understand how your linked question answers my question.

What is your answerable CS question? You express two wishes.

@greybeard actually I want to use Savitch theorem.

(That is a statement. A question might read "How do I start to prove this applying the…?")

@greybeard you are nitpicking, even if it was not in a interrogative form, what OP asked was pretty clear.

I’m pretty sure this exact question was asked before, not so long ago. The asker might have deleted it. I wonder whether it comes from some homework set.

I don’t think you can prove this directly using Savitch’s theorem, as Savitch’s theorem only guarantees $L\in\mathsf{DSPACE}((\log n)^2)$ for languages from $\mathsf{NL}=\mathsf{NSPACE}(\log n)$, whereas the problem here is $\oplus\mathsf L$-complete, hence likely not in NL. You are probably only supposed to use the idea of the proof of Savitch’s theorem to solve the exercise.
